# Need to split docx file based on string using docx4j Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I am new to `Docx4j` ,Need help to split `docx` file based on string using `docx4j` Java,So that it writes output into multiple files.

I tried to do the same using Apache POI and got the output,however when tried to convert it into HTML, got issues on style missing,also added styles later, still facing the same issue.

Below is the code using apache poi:

```
public static int pos = 0;
    public static int posc = 0;
    public static String ind = "n";
    final static int DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException, XmlException {

        File file = null;
        File outfilep = null;
        File outfilec = null;

        File dir = new File(PropertyUtils.getProperty("INPUT_DIR"));
        String[] files = dir.list();

        if (files.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("The directory is empty");
        } else {
            for (String aFile : files) {
                System.out.println(aFile);
                file = new File(PropertyUtils.getProperty("INPUT_DIR") + aFile
                        + "/" + aFile + ".docx");
                outfilep = new File(PropertyUtils.getProperty("INPUT_DIR")
                        + aFile + "/" + aFile + "-Product.docx");

                outfilec = new File(PropertyUtils.getProperty("INPUT_DIR")
                        + aFile + "/" + aFile + "-Component.docx");

                // Write Soruce file
            }
        }

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file));

        XWPFDocument destDoc = new XWPFDocument();

        copyLayout(doc, destDoc);

        XWPFDocument destDocc = new XWPFDocument();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfilep);
        OutputStream outc = new FileOutputStream(outfilec);

        for (IBodyElement bodyElement : doc.getBodyElements()) {

            BodyElementType elementType = bodyElement.getElementType();

            if (elementType.name().equals("PARAGRAPH")) {

                XWPFParagraph pr = (XWPFParagraph) bodyElement;

                if (pr.getText().contains("CONSTRUCTION DETAILS:"))

                {
                    ind = "y";
                    System.out.println("ind is Y++++++++++++");
                }

                if (ind == "n")

                {

                    copyStyle(doc, destDoc,
                            doc.getStyles().getStyle(pr.getStyleID()));

                    XWPFParagraph dstPr = destDoc.createParagraph();

                    dstPr.createRun();

                    pos = destDoc.getParagraphs().size() - 1;

                      CTPPr ppr = pr.getCTP().getPPr();
                        if (ppr == null) ppr = pr.getCTP().addNewPPr();
                        CTSpacing spacing = ppr.isSetSpacing()? ppr.getSpacing() : ppr.addNewSpacing();
                        spacing.setAfter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
                        spacing.setBefore(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
                        spacing.setLineRule(STLineSpacingRule.AUTO);
                        spacing.setLine(BigInteger.valueOf(240));

                    destDoc.setParagraph(pr, pos);
//                  System.out.println("prod "
//                           + destDoc.getParagraphArray(pos).getParagraphText());

                }

                else {
                    copyStyle(doc, destDocc,
                            doc.getStyles().getStyle(pr.getStyleID()));

                    XWPFParagraph dstPrr = destDocc.createParagraph();

                    dstPrr.createRun();

                    pos = destDocc.getParagraphs().size() - 1;
                      CTPPr ppr = pr.getCTP().getPPr();
                        if (ppr == null) ppr = pr.getCTP().addNewPPr();
                        CTSpacing spacing = ppr.isSetSpacing()? ppr.getSpacing() : ppr.addNewSpacing();
                        spacing.setAfter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
                        spacing.setBefore(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
                        spacing.setLineRule(STLineSpacingRule.AUTO);
                        spacing.setLine(BigInteger.valueOf(240));

                    destDocc.setParagraph(pr, pos);
////                    System.out.println("comp  "
////                             + destDoc.getParagraphArray(pos).getParagraphText());
                }



            } else if (elementType.name().equals("TABLE")) {

                XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable) bodyElement;

                if (ind == "n")

                {

                    copyStyle(doc, destDoc,
                            doc.getStyles().getStyle(table.getStyleID()));

                    destDoc.createTable();

                     pos = destDoc.getTables().size() - 1;

                    destDoc.setTable(pos, table);

//                   System.out.println("prodtable   "       + destDoc.getParagraphArray(pos).getParagraphText());

                } 
                else {

                    copyStyle(doc, destDocc,
                            doc.getStyles().getStyle(table.getStyleID()));

                    destDocc.createTable();

                     pos = destDocc.getTables().size() - 1;

                    destDocc.setTable(pos, table);

//                  System.out.println("comptable   "        + destDoc.getParagraphArray(pos).getParagraphText());
                }


            }
        }

        destDoc.write(out);
        destDocc.write(outc);
    }

    // Copy Styles of Table and Paragraph.
    private static void copyStyle(XWPFDocument srcDoc, XWPFDocument destDoc,
            XWPFStyle style) {
        if (destDoc == null || style == null)
            return;

        if (destDoc.getStyles() == null) {
            destDoc.createStyles();
        }

        List<XWPFStyle> usedStyleList = srcDoc.getStyles().getUsedStyleList(
                style);
        for (XWPFStyle xwpfStyle : usedStyleList) {
            destDoc.getStyles().addStyle(xwpfStyle);
        }
    }

      private static void copyLayout(XWPFDocument srcDoc, XWPFDocument destDoc)
        {
            CTPageMar pgMar = srcDoc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar();

            BigInteger bottom = pgMar.getBottom();
            BigInteger footer = pgMar.getFooter();
            BigInteger gutter = pgMar.getGutter();
            BigInteger header = pgMar.getHeader();
            BigInteger left = pgMar.getLeft();
            BigInteger right = pgMar.getRight();
            BigInteger top = pgMar.getTop();

            CTPageMar addNewPgMar = destDoc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr().addNewPgMar();

            addNewPgMar.setBottom(bottom);
            addNewPgMar.setFooter(footer);
            addNewPgMar.setGutter(gutter);
            addNewPgMar.setHeader(header);
            addNewPgMar.setLeft(left);
            addNewPgMar.setRight(right);
            addNewPgMar.setTop(top);

            CTPageSz pgSzSrc = srcDoc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgSz();

            BigInteger code = pgSzSrc.getCode();
            BigInteger h = pgSzSrc.getH();
            Enum orient = pgSzSrc.getOrient();
            BigInteger w = pgSzSrc.getW();

            CTPageSz addNewPgSz = destDoc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr().addNewPgSz();

            addNewPgSz.setCode(code);
            addNewPgSz.setH(h);
            addNewPgSz.setOrient(orient);
            addNewPgSz.setW(w);
        }
```

Comment: maybe you could share some of the code you have tried, and then maybe someone could help point out where the problem lies.

Comment: If you dont post any code or errors it's going to be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will solve the issue.

```
public class SplitUsingDocx4j {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Docx4JException
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Docx4JException,
        FileNotFoundException {
    File dir = new File(PropertyUtils.getProperty("INPUT_DIR"));
    String[] files = dir.list();
    File file = null;
    if (files.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("The directory is empty");
    } else {
        for (String aFile : files) {
            System.out.println(aFile);

            file = new File(PropertyUtils.getProperty("INPUT_DIR") + aFile
                    + "/" + aFile + ".docx");
        }
    }

    // Creating new documents
    WordprocessingMLPackage doc1 = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    WordprocessingMLPackage doc2 = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

    // loading existing document
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
            .load(new java.io.File(file.getPath()));
    MainDocumentPart tempDocPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    List<Object> obj = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent();

    // for copying styles from existing doc to new docs
    StyleDefinitionsPart sdp = tempDocPart.getStyleDefinitionsPart();
    Styles tempStyle = sdp.getJaxbElement();
    doc1.getMainDocumentPart().getStyleDefinitionsPart()
            .setJaxbElement(tempStyle);
    doc2.getMainDocumentPart().getStyleDefinitionsPart()
            .setJaxbElement(tempStyle);

    boolean flag = false;
    for (Object object : obj) {
        if (!flag) {
            if (object.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("CONSTRUCTION DETAILS:")) {
                flag = true;
            }
            doc1.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(object);
        } else {
            doc2.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(object);
        }

    }
    String fileName = file.getName().toString().replace(".docx", "");
    doc1.save(new File(fileName + "-1.docx"));
    doc2.save(new File(fileName + "-2.docx"));
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a docx is easy enough to do in a brute force kind of a way: you can delete the content (paragraphs etc) you don't want, then save the result.

This way, the original relationships will stay intact, but your docx container may be bigger than necessary, since it might have images etc which are no longer used.

Done this way, there are still things you need to look out for:

- splitting between a bookmark start and end tag (same for comments)
- automatic numbering might give the wrong start number, unless you set start at

Obviously you could write code to address such issues.

Alternatively, with our commercial Enterprise edition of docx4j, you can use its "merge" code to say you want say paragraphs X to Y, and it'll give you a docx containing only that (ie no extraneous images in the docx container, split bookmarks taken care of etc).

Comment: I have only paragraphs and tables in my document,is there any other way apart from commercial Enterprise edition of docx4j, as I tried with com.plutext.merge.DocumentBuilder, that is coporate patron.

Comment: Yes, as described above: clone the docx, then delete from the content list all but the bits you want, then save.  An easy do-it-yourself approach you can build on.